# Does anyone know what happened to my render?

Tags: rendering

I've been working on this scene for a while now and have never had any troubles at all until this afternoon. For some reason, the render (both in viewport and exported) now just come out as noise and I have no idea why. Does anyone have any ideas? The only action I performed since the last successful render was a Boolean (applied) to create the pit. As you can see from the screenshot, no other views have been affected...

[image]

Comment: Did you have used Camera Depth of Field? If you post blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ you could get faster and better answer.

Comment: @LukeD That was it, thank you! I thought deleting the focus object would reset the DOF settings but it obviously doesn't. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object used as the focal point for Depth of Field was probably removed in the boolean operation and thus the focus distance was set to 0. Choose a new focal point object or set the distance manually.